# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private datas::__construct() from invalid context in Stack trace: #0 include() #1 {main} thrown in C

Tags: php

```
class datas {

    public $host = DB_HOST;
    public $user = DB_USER;
    public $pass = DB_PASS;
    public $db_name = DB_NAME;


    public $link;
    public $error;

        private function __construct(){

            $this->connect();

        } 

    private function connect(){

        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->db_name);

        if(!$this->link){

            $this->error ="COnnection failed" . $this->connect_error; 
        }


}
```

how can I solve this

Answer (score 2):

The `__construct()` function should be `public`, not `private`. Note that the properties `$host`, `$user`, `$pass`, `$db_name`, `$link`, `$error` could be declared private, since they probably should not be accessible from outside the object.

```
class datas {

    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $db_name = DB_NAME;


    private $link;
    private $error;

        public function __construct(){

            $this->connect();

        } 

    private function connect(){

        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->db_name);

        if(!$this->link){

            $this->error ="COnnection failed" . $this->connect_error; 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Also, the `connect()` method is missing the closing bracket.
And it might be a good idea to use PDO instead http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php